# dbus custom types over xml prototype

Tags: xml, qt, dbus

I’m using DBUS declaring my methods in the xml files and then I use qdbusxml2cpp to generate my .h and .cpp files. I can use the native types (like “s”, “i”, “b”) pretty well but I need to use a custom type.
I know I have to add the annotation to the xml file but I can’t figure out how to specify my type.

Let’s say this is my class:

```
typedef enum{...} TestAttribute
class Test
{
public:
  //const, deconst, operators...

private:
    TestAttribute enumerator;
}
```

How can I pass this kind of object as argument of a method in the xml?

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17488452) help?